# Content swinging to left on mobile device what could cause this

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

www.yourtechpros.co.uk/test/

If you see the content is fine on a computer but on a mobile device there is a gap to the right with no content there just a white space? i've checked over the code of the media query and all seems to be fine, can anyone assist?

Ive checked all the code over and tried to adjust all the content inside

www.yourtechpros.co.uk/test/

Comment: Can you post screenshot of what happening instead of posting url ? If you post url and later you will fix it other people who search the same problem will not understand if that question fit their problem

Comment: Hi @LearningInProgress welcome to SO. There are couple of reasons for issue in mobile 1. There is no meta for viewport is defined. 2. This site is not responsive for mobile. 3. "Request for Callback" CTA is given with position fixed, that is pushing the content to left.

Comment: @Selvam HI, i've tried putting the Request callback CTA to the left fixed and there is still the space to the right, something else must be causing it

Comment: You should really take more pride in asking. You should try to isolate the issue in a separate environment (like codepen or jsfiddle) so that it boild down to one issue without all the noise. You can do this by copy/pasting all of your code and the step-by-step taking away parts with the issue still being there. Maybe at that point you found a solution for yourself. If you have such a [mcve], you can post your issue here along with the condensed code.

Comment: @pavelbere sadly I cannot, I'm dont have a mobile emulator on my computer I am using my mobile phone to display the mobile website

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest adding a viewport meta tag? You will see that the entire website changes dimensions.

Add this to the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

More info can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Extra support:
Checked your page: add the following

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .callbackicon {
        display: none;
    }
    .aboutabccleaning {
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

And change:

```
.frame {
    width: 130%;
}
```

too:

```
.frame {
    width: 100%;
}
```

EXTRA extra support:

If you remove the margin from `.aboutabccleaning` the white space will go away.

Comment: Sadly using this will screw up the rotating images at the top, is there another way to get rid of the space to the right without this metatag?

Comment: Mate your a star! i've updated for you to check, it wasnt the  callback icon but the .aboutabcleaning div, (the frame you must have checked mid change from me hehe i had this at 100 before set it to 130 to make sure it wasnt that)

Comment: there is only a tiny gap to the right now, what else could this be? ive set all of the widths to 100% now

Comment: Updated the answer. But removing margins will solve your "final" problem.

Comment: Hi mate honestly appreciate ALL of your help you've been star so far, if you have discord or anything id love to take it. So i removed the margin but there still seems to be the gap

Comment: No problem, I'm currently at work hahaha
But there is a large left value on `.contactinfo`. And `.aboutabccleaning` has a large width value. Removing these values fixes it somewhat.

Comment: That seems to have done it mate, absolute legend how do i upvote you or give you some kudos? + PM me your discord

Comment: It's oke, you can mark this answer as the solution and you give my some points. I'm just here to help other people, not here for the fame haha

Cheers mate!